When executing R source, how to split frame and start R in the new frame?
I have the same problem mentioned in this 2012 R mailing list post:
"My work habit
would be to open *.R, then [Ctrl-C Ctrl-C to run a block of code], hoping that

the window would automatically split, and
the R session would always open in THE OTHER window.

ESS pursues the opposite approach, of
starting R in the current window, so that if you have an R file
open, R covers it over. I hate that completely. You have to go
through a dance of splitting, choosing the other one, and then
starting R.  But I bet if you try, you can script it  up.
I had this behavior in my emacs set up for years, without I believe any special Emacs script, but recently upgraded ESS version 20240516.811 and lost it. Is there a way to recover it? I'm not sure which version of ESS I had before the upgrade but I believe it was from 2019.
I did also upgrade emacs at the same time from 25 to 30. But I noticed that my python shells still open the desired way, so I imagine this is a change to ESS and not emacs defaults.

Hello and welcome! If you put the versions of what you are using, it will help people answer your question. Here are some questions to help guide you.
What version of ESS was working? Which version did you upgrade to?
Did you upgrade or change anything other than ESS? What Emacs version are you using?
